# Displaying all values when python dictionary key has a value that is a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am seriously stuck and would appreciate a flashlight pointing in the right direction. I have a list with that I am importing as a text file. It has names and each row is numbered. The names repeat themselves 1, 2, or 3 times.
The goal is to have the output be {Key : [ , , ]...}. I have only managed to have one of the values show up.

```py
dictionary = {}
with open('%Filename%') as f:
    for line in f:
        num, key = line.strip().split()
        dictionary[key] = [num]
print(dictionary)
```

I expect the output to be `{'USA': ['15','91','99']...}`
Instead, I am get just `{'USA': ['99]...}`
​

Comment: you are replacing values in each iteration, not appending them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collection.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
with open('%Filename%') as f:
    for line in f:
        num, key = line.strip().split()
        dictionary[key].append(num)
print(dictionary)
```

---

or `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
dictionary = {}
with open('%Filename%') as f:
    for line in f:
        num, key = line.strip().split()
        dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(num)
print(dictionary)
```

- **Note:** You need to use `list.append` to append element to your list.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {}
with open('%Filename%') as f:
    for line in f:
        num, key = line.strip().split()
        if not key in dictionary:
            dictionary[key] = []
        dictionary[key].append(num)
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy fix using [dict.get](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/dictionary_get.htm):

```
dictionary = {}
with open('%Filename%') as f:
    for line in f:
        num, key = line.strip().split()
        dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, []) + [num]
print(dictionary)
```